# How to iterate through ArrayList and only add them to new List if the attribute match?

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `Person` objects and class `Person` has the following attributes:

- `name`
- `age`
- `birthday`

I want to iterate through the first `ArrayList` - `persons` - and save them in another `ArrayList` - `solution` - but only if the `name` is not already in `solution`.

Actually I think it is an easy problem but I always get duplicates in `solution`.

Here is the code:

```
   for (Iterator<Person> iterator = persons.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Person p1= iterator.next();
        for (Person p2 : persons) {
            if( p1 != null && p2!= null && p1.getName() == p2.getName()) {
                persons.set(persons.indexOf(p2), null);
            }
        }
        if(p1 != null) {
            solution.add(p1);
        }
    }
```

With this code I still get duplicates in `solution`. I think because the first iterator with `p1` does not update itself if I set the person to null in the inner `for` loop.

Maybe someone has an easier idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are `equals` and `hashCode` overridden in your `Person` class (please post the code of that class)? And I see you're using `p1.getName() == p2.getName()` to compare strings, that won't work as you may be expecting.

Comment: `dont want to add` is not what this code is doing, it is setting `null` the ones that are duplicated; better IMO, is to do what you wrote, that is, start with empty (second) list and for each element of first list, if it is not in second list, add it

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement the `Comparable` interface in your `Person` class, along with `equals` and `hashCode` methods
2. What you are after is in fact simply a `Set`, so you simply need to convert your list to a Set in order to remove duplicates.

   `Set<Person> uniquePeople = new HashSet(allPeople);`
3. An alternative is to use the Java 8 streams API which offers a `distinct` operator

   `List<Person> uniquePeople = allPeople.stream().distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

I got it now ...

thank you you helped me

i added a compareName function to my Person class and now he compare the strings right ...